# Typescript Array find element by index

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Finding and assigning a CategoryApi object having categoryId

```
export class CategoryApi {
    categoryId: number;
    name: string;
}

categories: CategoryApi[];
selectedCategory: CategoryApi;

selectedCategory = categories.findByIndex(2); //looking for categoryApi by categoryId = 2
```

I found this javascript option but Typescript is complaining about function

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Comment: Most simplest approach would be this `selectedCategory = categories.forEach(catApi => { if(catApi.id == requiredId) return catApi})`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no such method **findByIndex** in JS, the only method is **findIndex**.

You can use the **filter** or the **find** method to get the item by index:

// ES2015

```
selectedCategory = categories.find(item => item.categoryId === 1);
```

// ES5

```
selectedCategory = categories.filter(item => item.categoryId === 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find method:

```
selectedCategory = categories.find(c => c.categoryApi == 2);
```

The problem is, that the `find` function isn't listed in the typings-file.

First, ignore the error-message and try it!

Second, you could edit the typings-file:

1. change `find` with `filter` and press F12 (go to declaration)
2. copy this line in the typings-file and rename the function to `find` and the returned value to single-object instead of an array!
3. save that file
4. rename your back `filter` to `find` in your code..